# Proof: Need help with Rodrigues's formula for finding coefficent of $x^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I’m having problems with proving Rodrigues’s formula. I’m stuck on expanding $$u=D^n((x^2-1)^n)$$ (where D is the differential operator) to “show that the coefficient of x^n in u is $$(2n)!/(n!)$$”. I’ve used Leibniz’s formula to differentiate it n times via difference of squares and got to this:$$\sum_{k=0}^n ((x+1)^{n-k}(x-1)^k\frac{(n!)^3}{(k!)^2((n-k)!)^2})$$but I’m still no closer to proving it. Can someone please give me a hint with this.

Comment: If you only care about the coefficient of $x^n$ in $u$ then you don't need to work out what all of $u$ is. Now think about which coefficient of $(x^2-1)^n$ you actually need to work out (you only need one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Expand the argument $(x^2 - 1)^n$ of $D^n$ using the Binomial Theorem,
$$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} a^k b^{n - k}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've solved it now.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found the answer helpful.